# "Please ensure you have JAVA_HOME points to JDK rather than JRE" message

Tags: 12.10, java, android, jdk, jre

I have java installed

```
aaa@ubuntu:~$ whereis java
java: /usr/bin/java /usr/bin/X11/java /usr/local/java /usr/share/java
aaa@ubuntu:~$ whereis javac
javac: /usr/bin/javac /usr/bin/X11/javac
```

and **etc/profile**

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_17
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin
JRE_HOME=/usr/local/java/jre1.7.0_17
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JRE_HOME/bin
export JAVA_HOME
export JRE_HOME
export PATH
```

However, when I run Android Studio, it says:

```
tools.jar in not in Android Studio classpath. Please ensure you have JAVA_HOME points 
to JDK rather than JRE.
```

How do I fix it?

**update**

```
sudo update-alternatives --get-selections | grep ^java 
java                           manual   /usr/local/java/jre1.7.0_17/bin/java
javac                          manual   /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_17/bin/javac
javaws                         manual   /usr/local/java/jre1.7.0_17/bin/javaws


java -version
java version "1.7.0_17"
```

Comment: echo java_home gives me /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_17

Comment: You should have `.jinfo` files, but I have updated my answer to set the update alternatives without them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to use the jre version in the jdk, you can do so by executing

```
    sudo update-alternatives --set java /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_17/jre/bin/java
    sudo update-alternatives --set javaws /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_17/jre/bin/javaws
```

Normally this can be done by using `update-java-alternatives` with a `.jinfo` file, but for some reason you can't find them on your system.

Comment: `java version "1.7.0_17"` but I didn't do what you suggested me. do I need it?

Comment: which java -- /usr/bin/java

Comment: I updated my topic4

Comment: I mean, I cannot launch it. `ls /usr/lib/jvm/.*.jinfo` -- No such file or directory

Comment: try `sudo updatedb` and when it's done `locate *.jinfo`

Comment: doesn't give you any output?

Comment: update-alternatives: error: alternative /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_91/jre/bin/java for java not registered; not setting

Comment: @DmitryShvedov Please have a look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/388593/setup-jdk-for-android-studio (most likely the version numbers are now different)

Comment: @GerhardBurger Thanks Gerhard, seems I had JRE installed and not JDK