# Setup JDK for android studio

Tags: java, android, openjdk, jdk

I was setting up android studio and got this

[image]

So I followed the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/296694/please-ensure-you-have-java-home-points-to-jdk-rather-than-jre-message) and used

```
sudo update-alternatives --set java /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_17/jre/bin/java

sudo update-alternatives --set javaws /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_17/jre/bin/javaws
```

But this gave me `update-alternatives: error: alternative /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_17/jre/bin/java for java not registered; not setting`

How can I fix this and get android studio working? I am have openJDK installed.

Comment: Did you try installing Oracle's java? I think I had a similar problem with android studio

Comment: @AmithKK I did download it but I haven't installed it yet. I will try that now

Comment: I have extracted the Oracle JDK but how do I install it?

Comment: see this http://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-to-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file

Comment: @qwertyk31 did you installed any java version (preferable the OpenJDK)?

Comment: @Braiam I have OpenJDK now

Comment: Nothing better?

Comment: @Braiam What to you mean?

Comment: If something changed? Or still the same error?

Comment: I have always had OpenJDK installed

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the exact 1.7.17 version is different now and the `jdk1.7.0_17` does not exists, so use the interactive command to change the `java` or `javaws` alternative.

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config java
There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).
  Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1061      auto mode
* 1            /usr/lib/jvm/j2re1.7-oracle/bin/java             316       manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1061      manual mode
Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 1

$ sudo update-alternatives --config javaws
There are 3 choices for the alternative javaws (providing /usr/bin/javaws).
  Selection    Path                                              Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/javaws   1071      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/j2re1.7-oracle/bin/javaws             316       manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/javaws   1061      manual mode
  3            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/javaws   1071      manual mode
Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 1
```

It's a lot less likely to make mistakes with this. :)

Answer (score 0):

May be this can hepls to somebody:
I had some problem. And i fix it changing symlink /etc/alternatives/java from openJDK to Oracle JDK (you must install it previous).
To install Oracle JDK i used this instructions:
http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html

Comment: -1 for messing around with symlinks yourself rather than using a tool like `update-alternatives`.

Comment: @gertvdijk What do u think this tool does? And what kind of messing? It's exactly same and tool will work fine with this alias.

Comment: Oh I know: http://askubuntu.com/a/233192/88802 But as I explained in my answer in this question, it's a lot less likely to make errors with using a tool to select the right path and it adjusts to the situation of the user (e.g. other versions).